# Lua script optimization

Tags: c#-4.0, lua, redis, servicestack.redis

I am trying to connect redis via c# using using `ServiceStack.Redis`.

I have written below code to validate number based on the key specified.

`argv[1]` is key

`argv[2]` is number

```
string strScript = " local intCurrentVal = redis.call('GET', '' .. ARGV[1] .. ''); \n"
   + "if (tonumber(intCurrentVal) <= 0 ) then return 1  elseif (  (tonumber(intCurrentVal)) - (tonumber('' .. ARGV[2] .. '')) < 0 ) then return 0 end;"
   + "local intUpdatedVal = redis.call('SET', '' .. ARGV[1] .. '',( intCurrentVal -  tonumber('' .. ARGV[2] .. '')));"
   + "local intCurr = redis.call('GET',  '' .. ARGV[1] .. ''); return intCurr";
```

logical steps:

- get the current value
- check if current value should not be less then or equal to 0
- check if current value - passed value should not be less then O
- if current value - passed is not less then 0 then set the (current value - passed) as the current value
- get the current value

Is it possible to optimize and tune the following lua script for performance. please help.

Comment: It has to be inside transaction block.

Comment: what transaction block?

Comment: About how many thousand transactions per second are we talking? Have you profiled and found that the Lua script is the issue?

Comment: executing all the set of statements in one go.

Comment: It is too early to say that lua scripts got issue. I just need to find tune that. I got the solution

Answer (score 1):

Original formatting is awful -- so is often performance.

```
local key = tostring(ARGV[1])
local number = tonumber(ARGV[2])

local current = tonumber(redis.call('GET', key))

if current <= 0 then
    return 1
elseif current < number then
    return 0
end

redis.call('SET', key, current - number)
return redis.call('GET', key)
```

Further optimization steps may include: localizing of global functions (like to string, tonumber, etc.), caching compiled chunk at LUA_REGISTRYINDEX table.

Comment: I do agree with you but I want to incorporate the same inside one transaction block, that is the reason to use lua script.

Comment: Last 2 lines I have replaced it when INCRBY api calls of redis